# Glue Records creation

Tags: dns, nameserver, domain-registrar

I need some information on the following issue, as I would like to have it clear on my mind.

I have a VPS server. All my sites hosted on this VPS are using as NameServer .gr domain, like ns1.greekdomain.gr & ns2.greekdomain.gr . The .gr domain name is a domain I own with a greek registar.

Now, I want to move 2 websites with .co.uk domain names to my VPS. 
The co.uk domain names are registered with a UK based registar. 
When I went in the domain management panel, I did changed the nameservers of my domains to my ns.greekdomain.gr ns.

However the panel returns an error about invalid nameservers. 
After digging, I found that my nameservers are not valid because they do not exist as records in the .co.uk registry.

And here it starts my big trouble. 
The .co.uk registart tells me that I have to ask my hosting provider / .gr registar to create a new record to the .uk registry for my nameservers.

The .gr registar tells me that my uk registar needs to create a new record for my ns.

From Nominet (.co.uk) registry, the one employee tells me that I need to ask my uk registar, the other employee (seemed to not understand what I was asking) told me that they cannot change my nameservers for me, and she told me to contact anyone else (old hosting provider, uk registar, .gr registar) to help me with that.

I can't find help from nobody. I try since the last week to transfer my websites to my VPS and I can't.

So, the question is who is responsible and who is able to create glue records for my nameservers ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed to gather the required information. 
The co.uk registry support, said that they hold only glue records only for .uk nameservers.
For ns of other TLD's they refer to the registry of that TLD.
So, actually in my case described above there is no need to create such records in the uk registry.

But, in cases where such nameservers won't work for uk domain names, uk registars are able to access and can submit new glue records.

In my case the registar didn't do that. I finally had to use other .com nameservers which worked.

Hope this will help anyone that will need similar information, as I was seeking for such info for about 1 week, with many calls and emails with registars, registries and hosting companies.